# question regarding email

Tags: php

In `$_SESSION['cart']` there are multiple records with table. But when I trying to send email. Im only getting one table data. Please help me

```
session_start();
$message = array();
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) 
{
    $message ="<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Image</td>
                    <td><a href=".$value['txturl'].">
                        <img width =150  src=".$value['product_image']." /></a></td
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Product Name</td>
                    <td>".$value['product_name']."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Price</td>
                    <td>".$value['product_price']."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shop Name</td>
                    <td>".$value['shop_name']."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td>".$value['Quantity']."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Color</td>
                    <td>".$value['color']."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product_Type</td>
                    <td>".$value['Product_Type']."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Remarks</td>
                    <td>".$value['Remarks']."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Final Price</td>
                    <td>".$value['final_price']."</td>
                </tr>

                </table>"; 
}
    $to = "";
$subject = "Order Details";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$from = "";
$headers .= 'From: Admin - Order Details <admin.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: print_r($_SESSION); post the results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$message` should be a string.

Start with:

```
$message = '';
```

And then each time through your loop, append the html:

```
$message .= " .... ";
```

Comment: @awn Should I remove this `$message = array();`?

Comment: Yes.  Put `$message = '';` instead.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
$message =
```

to

```
$message .=
```

otherwise you just overwrite on every loop

Answer (score 0):

try to use

> $message =' ';

and inside for loop use `$message .='<table>.......</table';`